# Rails 5.1: Passing in array to where query does not search across multiple values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5.1

I'm in the process of upgrading my Rails app to 5.1.x. 
I've noticed that when I try a query such as: 
`Book.where(genre: ['mystery', 'romance']).count`, 

 the SQL generated is 
 
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books" WHERE "books"."genre" = $1   [["genre", "[\"mystery\", \"romance\"]"]]`

instead of what you'd expect: 
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "books" WHERE "books"."genre" IN ('mystery', 'romance')`

What has changed? Is there some way to keep the old behavior? The 5.1.3 doesn't suggest that this functionality has changed:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-where

Thanks!

Comment: What column type is `genre`?

Comment: Based on how the quotes are being escaped in the `SELECT` statement it looks like you may be passing a string like `'["mystery", "romance"]'` instead of an array like `["mystery", "romance"]`.  Could you check the `class` of what is being passed into the `where`?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Found my problem! Thanks to Robert's question the other day, I realized my problem is because `genre` is saved to the DB as a string but is used as a `Genre` object. Previously, I'd been using `serialize :genre Genre`, but for some reason it wasn't using the right values in the where clause properly.

I created a new `GenreType < ActiveRecord::Type` and added `attribute :genre GenreType.new`  and voila!

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html